# React Native super slow rendering

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to mobile app development but have developed for the web for many years.

With React Native I am rendering a list of just 50 rows, each containing only two very short texts (~20 characters) and two small images (size 30x30). This consistently takes a whopping 400-700ms to render and I just can't solve it.

The same list on the same phone in a web browser renders instantly. And yes, I know about FlatList/virtualized list, but even with just the 20 entries that fill the screen it takes 300ms.

Are these completely normal rendering durations for React Native and I just have to accept it or does it look I am doing something completely wrong?

The Expo performance monitor shows a consistent 60 fps for UI and JS during the whole slow rendering, btw. And there are no animations.

Comment: did you check this link ? https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Thank you, but I feel that the FlatList is not helping me here, especially when things still fit on one screen without scrolling.

Comment: Ideally `FlatList` is to be used when you have a very large amount of data. If you have say `30-40` records max then you can try using a `ScrollView` instead. having said that, performance-wise `FlatList` is better.

Comment: have your checked out react-native-fast-image? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am preloading all images already and that actually made a small difference.